# Subscribe to author?

Tags: plugin-development, database, users

Basically, I want to follow the author by other WordPress users. Whenever an author posts new post subscribed users need to get notification by email.

If it's not already there, I can create a plugin for this. But I need an idea to store the data. Should I go for custom table or is there a better way to store default table structure.

Comment: Did you read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41941/73?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed plugin called [Wp Subcribe Author](http://code-cocktail.in/portfolio/wp-subscribe-author/) to subscribe author by email. You can [download](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-subscribe-author/) and use it from WordPress site.

I used custom custom table structure, I feel that's good, because I don't want to mess up with database performance !

Comment: You should not create a new table for each blog in a multi-site. And `CHARSET=latin1` – why? Default is UTF-8 in WordPress.

Comment: @toscho : Thanks for your review. I will update it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider installing [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me) and activating the Email Subscriptions module.